# WebDriver - Anyway to change default download location?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Selenium-webdriver + java for automating my application.

Is there any way to change the default "Download Location" of a Browser via Webdriver / Desired capabilities / any other approach?

Answer (score 3):

Download location can be changed to custom download path by setting preference value to `2` for `browser.download.folderList` like following:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "directory_path_to_save_file");
```

By doing so, you can download file in the directory you mentioned while creating profile.

And then, create a browser instance by passing `profile`:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a clean way to do it. You can use `webdriverManager` to set up the browser, e.g chrome and then override chrome's default download location using `ChromeOptions` with some `DesiredCapabilities`

Try this code block:

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();   //This sets up chrome driver
    String downloadDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadDir);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

To use WebDriverManager, you must add this dependency to your maven project (there is also a gradle version):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```