# Setting up a custom browser profile in selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747836/webdriver-anyway-to-change-default-download-location) question suggests how to change the default download directory in a firefox profile that is to be later used by selenium. In my case I must download .pdf files by default to a certain directory. The problem is that using a new profile with every instance of a web driver prompts the download dialog box (no downloads are made by default).

Using the default profile garbles the current session with the existing one (if present).

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
// The default profile that is used "outside" of selenium
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = profile.getProfile("default");
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

In the default profile, the pdf files are downloaded as required without prompting for a download dialog.

How can I customize the profile the web driver uses so that pdf files are downloaded in selenium as well (without requiring confirmation on behalf of the user)?

Comment: `Using the default profile garbles the current session with the existing one (if present)` - did not completely get what is the problem if you use `default` profile?

Comment: It conflicts with the existing session (I am trying to import contacts from aol web mail)

Comment: Do you really need to "natively download a file" in the browser?   Why not use javascript to capture the file url and then make a download helper that downloads it separate from the browser.  No need to test a function of webbrowsers that is different on each type of browser and already well tested on each.

Comment: The URL is dynamically generated based on session variables and I'm not very familiar with how it may be captured  and writing a helper would take , possibly, too much time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser settings can be set as preferences within the web driver as follows:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv, application/csv, text/comma-separated-values");
        WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Simply add the MIME type of the file to the above preference list.